# Combination & permutation help!

Tags: permutations, combinations

[image]

I was thinking: 120 - 5C4 but the answer is 24.

Is anyone able to explain this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 1 seat occupied, there are 4 left. There are 4! = 24 ways to position the remaining persons.

Comment: Oh! That was easy... I got thrown off by 120 but it's just 5! . Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Martha is sitting in the middle seat (seat number $3$). The other $4$ friends can sit on any of the seats $1,2,4,5$.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are 5 seats, Martha ends up in a particular seat one fifth of the time. One fifth of 120 is 24.